# Set two tables on the same row with CSS

Tags: html, css

As I am not used to CSS, I would like to ask the best solution to apply format of a table like it would be two distinct tables juxtaposed :

[image]

To do so, I would make a class attribute to each td or th so that brown ones are brown and the rest blue.

Here is what I have done, but I'm have trouble to set the borders width properly and I am hoping for some help in CSS here :

```css
html {overflow: auto;}

div.dhtmlx_window_active, div.dhx_modal_cover_dv { position: fixed !important; }
body{width:99%;}
table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
table * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table thead * {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
.titlePrev {
 background-color: rgb(183, 222, 232);
}
.titlegeneriquedpt {
 background-color: rgb(196, 189, 151);
}
table tbody * {
 background-color: rgb(218, 238, 243);
}
.generiquedpt {
 background-color: rgb(238, 236, 225);
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table><thead>
 <tr>
  <th colspan=14 class="titlePrev">TEXT</th>
  <th colspan=13 class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</th>
 </tr><tr>
  <th colspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <th rowspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <th colspan=8>TEXT</th>
  <th colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</th>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=3 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <th colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</th>
 </tr><tr>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=3>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=4>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <th>TEXT</th>
  <th>TEXT</th>
 </tr></thead> 
 <tbody><tr>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr>
 </tr></tbody>
 <tfoot><tr>
  <th class="titlePrev" colspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>   
 </tr></tfoot> 
</table>
```

Do not worry about the colspan I set, as I will be needing it in the following tables in that page.

Comment: So you want to make the border also dotted or what? I don't understand what you are asking for...after comparing your screenshot and your snippet this is the only difference...

Comment: I want to make 2px borders at the limits of each table (top, bottom, right, left), dotted borders if possible where they are,  using the CSS file. I think using some `.generiquedpt:first-child` but even my `th:first-child, td:first-child {  border-left: 2px;}` doesn't override the other CSS rule.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll try out some stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution. However I dont know if it is effective or not. Here it goes:

```css
html {overflow: auto;}

div.dhtmlx_window_active, div.dhx_modal_cover_dv { position: fixed !important; }
body{width:99%;}
table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
table * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table thead * {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
.titlePrev {
 background-color: rgb(183, 222, 232);
}
.titlegeneriquedpt {
 background-color: rgb(196, 189, 151);
}
table tbody * {
 background-color: rgb(218, 238, 243);
}
.generiquedpt {
 background-color: rgb(238, 236, 225);
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px;
}

.bl{
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: medium;
}
.br{
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: medium;
}
.bt{
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: medium;
}
.bb{
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
}
```

```html
<table><thead>
 <tr class="bl br bt">
  <th colspan=14 class="titlePrev br">A</th>
  <th colspan=13 class="titlegeneriquedpt">B</th>
 </tr><tr class="bl br">
  <th colspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <th rowspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <th colspan=8 >TEXT</th>
  <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="br">TEXT</th>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=3 rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 >TEXT</th>
 </tr><tr class="bl br">
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=3>TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=4>TEXT</td>
  <td rowspan=2>TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr class="bl br">
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td class="br">TEXT</td>
  <td colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <th>TEXT</th>
  <th>TEXT</th>
 </tr></thead> 
 <tbody><tr class="bl br">
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td class="br">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr class="bl br">
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td class="br">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="generiquedpt ">TEXT</td>
 </tr><tr class="bl br">
 </tr></tbody>
 <tfoot><tr class="bl br bb">
  <th class="titlePrev" colspan=3>TEXT</th>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlePrev br">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt" colspan=2>TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>
  <td class="titlegeneriquedpt">TEXT</td>   
 </tr></tfoot> 
</table>
```

You just need to add the 4 classes according to where you want the border. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't know there was multiple class attribute, using spaces. Can you go further in detail with the dotted borders ? And do you think there would not be a better way to format the generiquedpt part, as it is from one cell to the end ?

Comment: to change tit into dotted just adapt the css accordingly using this "border-style: dotted;" as for the generiquedpt part, you need to adjust the position of the class / the position of the tables accordingly